# how to use jquery to transverse a javascript object

Tags: jquery, socket.io

Heres my client-side code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Alerter</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://www.example.com:8001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

       var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com:8001');
       socket.on('message', function (data) { do_message(data) });
     });

   function do_message(data){
     var $obj=$(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
     //now what goes in here? 
   };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript object I receive looks like

```
{
    "root": {
        "status": [
            "OK"
        ],
        "alert": [
            {
                "$": { "src": "web" },
                "time": [ "1349316382" ],
                "id": [ "user1" ]
            },
            {
                "$": { "src": "web" },
                "time": [ "1349316391" ],
                "id": [ "user2" ]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

And what I want to do is iterate over each of the "alert" entries and take appropriate action (the actual schema is a bit more complicated than I've shown above)

Are jQuery selectors the right tool for this task or should I got back to native javascript (ie getElementsByTagName or similar).  All the jQuery docs are based around selecting valid html tags from the DOM, I cant figure out how to select arbitary tags from the received message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the data using `$.forEach`:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$.each(obj['root']['alert'], function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.id);
});
```

Or you can just use regular JS:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var alerts = obj['root']['alert'];

for (var key in alerts) {
    var value = alerts[key];

    console.log(value.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the $.each from jQuery to iterate over your object .. Try this

```
console.log('status is : ' + data.root.status[0]);

     $.each(data.root.alert , function(i, value){
          console.log ('Dollar is : ' + value["$"]["src"]);
           console.log ('Time is : ' + value["time"][0]); 
           console.log ('ID is : ' + value["id"][0]); 
     });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hYYDP/)

Comment: Essentially the same answer as I ticked- sorry I cant mark two answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors cannot be used with plain JavaScript objects.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

> **Working With Plain Objects**
>   At present, the only operations supported
>   on plain JavaScript objects wrapped in jQuery are:
>   .data(),.prop(),.bind(), .unbind(), .trigger() and .triggerHandler().

You will have to iterate with jQuery.each() or a plain JavaScript loop.